# What does the time field indicate in ping statistics?

Tags: networking, linux-networking, ping

In the `ping` output on Linux, what does the *time* field indicate? It is obvious for individual packets, but not in the summary.

What took **5ms** in the output below?

[image: ping output]

It is not described in the man page. My OS is Debian Buster, using the `ping` binary from this package: https://packages.debian.org/buster/iputils-ping

Comment: What OS is this, and what version of ping?

Comment: @cutrightjm I have edited the question to include this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the current implementation of iputils-ping.

https://github.com/iputils/iputils/issues/193

This should show the complete time the command has been running.

Comparation with Version 20161105 from debian stretch which doesn't have this bug:

```
ping -c 4 1.1.1.1
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=34.1 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=28.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=29.9 ms
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=29.0 ms

--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 28.986/30.526/34.118/2.111 ms
```

Comment: Nice explanation! I was wondering why it was so low.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the answer. I wouldn't even consider that a core utility in the stable version of Debian could have such a blatant error in it's output.

Answer (score 1):

This time field means the total time it took to send and receive echo packets including delay time. So the total time for your entire ping operation. But what I do not understand is that the value its showing in your statistics! It should be much higher than 5ms.